# How to fill the gap between tablix and footer, with grey rectangle

Tags: vb.net, winforms, report-viewer2010

I'm using ReportViewer in MS Visual Studio 2010 and have a problem filling the rest of the the body to join the footer.

First I have tried: body contains a Tablix and an empty grey rectangle beneath it, higher than the Tablix, to fill the gap to the footer.  The body is 4.625" inch tall.
When displayed, the 3rd page has no data, but the excess rectangle creates it.

### Wanted Result With Rectangle (excluding page 3)

[image: Tablix is smaller than rectangle #1]

### Current Result With Rectangle

[image: Tablix is smaller than rectangle #2]

Second thing I have tried: body contains a  Tablix and a rectangle beneath it, same size.  The body is 1.75 in. tall.
The first page displays fine, since the data fills the entire body.

The second page displays the rest of the data, and it's blank between the last row of the tablix and the footer.

[image: Tablix is same size as rectangle]

I would like to have a grey rectangle showed between the las row of the tablix and the footer.

Answer (score 2):

All,

I have found an alternative, which is more easy:

I removed all the rectangles and put the backgrounds of header, body and footer to light grey, with borders.

I have played with my margins, to obtain a result close to what I wanted.

Marc S.